# how XBeanNamespaceHandler is used by ActiveMQ?

Tags: apache, spring, activemq-classic

I am interesting to know how ActiveMQ's xml is pared to generate its embedded broker. I found the following spring.handlers in the activemq-core-5.5.0.jar.

```
#Generated by xbean-spring
#Mon Mar 28 19:10:40 IST 2011
http\://activemq.apache.org/schema/core=org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler
```

This indicate that the XBeanNamespaceHandler is used however I have no idea how. Anybody out there got idea of how ActiveMQ use XBeanNamespaceHandler?

Thanks,

Comment: Just find file in /META-INF/services/org/apache/xbean/spring/http/activemq.apache.org/schema/core of the same jar. It seems that it is the mapping between XML elements and actual ActiveMQ classes. But I can't find document about how this file is read.

Comment: For example, how the authorizationPlugin is included into the broker. I can find no clue on how ActiveMQ do this.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation of such namespace handlers is described in [Appendix D. Extensible XML authoring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html) of Spring Reference.

Comment: Thanks, It describe the spring.handlers file. But I can't found information on apache.xbean.spring from the web, I suspect the XBeanNamespaceHandler is from this project.